# Member variable getting overridden with garbage value

Tags: c++, pointers

In a class, I have a member variable which is set when I call a method and am able to print it but it gets overridden when I try to print it a second time. 
Below is the approximate code of whats happening.

nodezero.h

```
#ifndef NODEZERO_H
#define NODEZERO_H
//does nothing but sets three properties let say m_a, m_b and m_c.
#endif
```

nodefirst.h

```
#ifndef NODEFIRST_H
#define NODEFIRST_H

#include "nodezero.h"

class nodefirst {
        public:
                nodezero* root=nullptr;
                void insert(int, int, int);
};
#endif
```

nodefirst.cpp

```
void nodefirst::insert(int a, int b, int c) {
        nodezero realnode = nodezero(a,b,c);
        nodezero* node = &realnode;
        root = node;
        return;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "nodezero.h"
#include "nodefirst.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
nodefirst nf;
nf.insert(1,2,3);
cout<<nf.root->n_a<<"test"<<nf.root->n_a;
```

When the cout is called, part before "test" is printed correctly as 1 but after test is some garbage value. 
Can someone please help me with this? I am not able to find what I am missing.

Comment: `nodezero realnode` is destroyed when control leaves `nodefirst::insert()`. The pointer to it (`root`) becomes dangling, and accessing stuff through it causes undefined behavior. Use `new` to create the node to make it outlive the function.

Comment: You probably wanted to have `root = new nodezero(1, 2, 3);`

Comment: Thanks guys. Missed the mistake somehow.